# Python Celery - How to separate log files

Tags: python, celery

By default the python celery package centralizes logs.
In my design specs, I would like to have the logs of each worker written to a separate file where the filename would match unique ids sent to the task.
Centrilized logs shows which worker the log is from but I could not figure out how to map the id to worker number.

To decentralize the logs, I tried:

```
import logging
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
app = Celery()
@app.task
def my_task(id):
    logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/%i.log' % id)
    my_package.do_somthing()
    logging.info('hi')
```

but this is not creating any log file.
Is there a way to separate the logs or a way to map worker numbers to ids so that I can generate separate logs?

---

**update:**

Reading http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#names
I tried this approach that still fails to make separate logs:

celeryconfig.py:

CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False

main.py

```
import logging
app = Celery()
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
@app.task(bind=True)
def my_task(self, id):
    self.request.logfile = '/tmp/%i.log' % id
    my_package.do_somthing()
    logging.info('hi')
```

Also, I discovered a blog: http://echorand.me/2012/08/14/celery-and-python-logging/
and tried it. It only would write the log message 'hi' to separate files but will continute to send logs from

```
my_package.do_somthing()
```

to standard output meaning that the logger is not fixed globally and passing around the logger is going to get very messy so that will not do.

---

**update**

I tried the code from the blog:
https://github.com/kouroshparsa/celery_separate_logging/tree/master/celery_example

when calling mylib/fire.py: burn method, the logging is not stored anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You have to disable celery logging first. You can do that by setting

```
 CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
```

in your config or you can use [Celery signals](https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#setup-logging).

Now If you run your workers, you wont see any information.

Lets write a simple logger which logs things to seperate files

```
def custom_logger(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join('/tmp/', name + '.log'), 'w')
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger


@app.task()
def add(x, y):

    task_id = add.request.id
    l = custom_logger(task_id)
    l.info("Testing Log")

    return x + y
```

For every tasks, this creates a new file with task id as name and logs whatever you want.

Comment: I updated the code with what I tried but it did not work. You mentioned putting the signal in the config. but I put it in the code. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I've uploaded the whole code: https://github.com/kouroshparsa/celery_separate_logging/tree/master/celery_example